# Can I use GPL 2+ (CKEditor v5) on a website with paid subscription?

Tags: gpl-2, website

I am creating a website on a platform - similar to WordPress - where the access to the website will be via paid subscription. I am selling to the end user a service. It is like I would replace WordPress editor with CKEditor and then restricted access to the website by a members plugin. The website is build using a proprietary web similar to wix. I have to pay for the website.

CKEditor is using https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license/

My understanding is I can use CKEditor v5 but I want to be sure.

Comment: Is it the CKEditor or the website that is (to be) GPLv2+ licensed?

Comment: @ruben2020 I updated the question. The CKEditor is GPLv2+licensed